# Does Ballerina support JSON navigation similar to the XML navigation?

Tags: json, ballerina

For XML files in Ballerina, if we want to access a node with a given name nested anywhere within the tree, we can access it using the following way.

```
// x/**/<name> - for every element e in x, retrieves every element named name in
// the descendants of e.
 xml f = x/**/<name>;
 io:println("f",f,"\n\n");
```

Is there a similar way to access a JSON object key with a given name that can be nested anywhere inside the main JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

> For XML files in Ballerina, if we want to access a node with a given name nested anywhere within the tree we can access it using the following way.

```
xml f = x/**/<name>;
io:println("f",f,"\n\n");
```

In summary, the OP refers to [Convenient XML navigation](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/169).

> Is there a similar way to access a JSON object key with a given name that can be nested anywhere inside the main JSON object?

**No**. At least not yet.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a similar way to access a JSON object key with a given name that can be nested anywhere inside the main JSON object?

No. But you can archive the required result by using optional field access and a query expression.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {
    json store = {
        store: {
            book: [
                {
                    category: "reference",
                    author: "Nigel Rees",
                    title: "Sayings of the Century"
                },
                {
                    category: "fiction",
                    author: "Evelyn Waugh",
                    title: "Sword of Honour"
                },
                {
                    category: "fiction",
                    author: "Herman Melville",
                    title: "Moby Dick"
                },
                {
                    category: "fiction",
                    author: "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                    title: "The Lord of the Rings"
                }
            ],
            bicycle: {
                color: "red",
                price: 19.95
            }
        }
    };

    json|error books = store?.store?.book;
    if books is error {
        return;
    }

    string[] titles = from json item in <json[]>books
        select check item?.title;
    io:println(titles);
}
```

If we take the above JSON example, we can solve the specific scenario with optional field access and a query expression.

Please refer these as well:

- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/access-optional-json-elements/
- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/query-expressions/